# How to calculate how many fields a circle with radius r will take up in a coordinate system

Tags: python, arrays, list, math, geometry

I wrote a function that "draws" a circle into a coordinate system (a 2d array/list):

```
def drawCircle(x,y,r,steps, draw=True):
        coords = []
        for n in range(steps):
            coords.append(((round(x + r * math.cos(2 * math.pi * (n / steps)))),round(y + r * math.sin(2 * math.pi * (n / steps)))))
        if draw:  
            for n in range(len(coords)):
                self.drawPixel(coords[n][0],coords[n][1])
        return list(set(coords))
```

It returns how many points are actually visible, because it overdraws some points.
My question:
(How) can I determine `steps` from `r`. That would make the function more efficient.

If I run

```
print(len(drawCircle(10, 10, r, 200)))
```

it gives me the answer I'm searching for.

```
for r in range(5,30):
    print(len(drawCircle(10, 10, r, 200)))
```

```
40
40
56
56
72
80
80
88
96
96
112
112
128
136
120
128
152
152
176
152
176
168
160
176
192
```

I can't see any pattern. The
`drawPixel(x,y)`
just does `list[y][x] = "#"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using trigonometry, exploit effective [Bresenham circle drawing algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bresenhams-circle-drawing-algorithm/).

[image]

It produces only distinct points.

Answer (score 1):

You might be missing that the number of coordinates/pixels you function returns depends on both the `r` and `step` variables. If `steps` is sufficiently large, the number the number of pixels wont increase with even bigger `steps`.

consider this:

```
for steps in range(200, 5000, 200):
    print(len(drawCircle(10, 10, 40, steps, draw=False))) 

Out [1]:
200
280
288
304
288
312
320
320
312
320
320
320
312
320
320
320
320
320
320
320
320
320
320
320
```

So you might want to get the smallest number of `steps` that gets you the largest possible number of coorditates/pixels.

That is a bit more challenging, and I can't think of a very straightforward way to calculate this. A "bruteforce" solution could be this

```
def drawCircle(x,y,r, draw=True):
        
        steps = 500
        n_pixels = 0
        n_pixels_prev = -1
        
        while n_pixels_prev < n_pixels:
            coords = []
            for n in range(steps):
                x_pix = round( x + r * math.cos(2 * math.pi * (n / steps)) )
                y_pix = round( y + r * math.sin(2 * math.pi * (n / steps)) )
                coords.append( (x_pix, y_pix)  )
                
            n_pixels_prev = n_pixels
            n_pixels = len(set(coords))
            steps += 1000
            
            
        if draw:  
            for n in range(len(coords)):
                self.drawPixel(coords[n][0],coords[n][1])
        return list(set(coords))
```

What it does is choose increasingly bigger values for `step` until it the number of pixels does not increase any more. The function then returns those coordinates. But this is not ideal as you can imagine.

Answer (score 1):

I am new to this, but if I understand correctly,
is this what you are looking for

```
import sympy as sy # a symbolic math module in numpy stack
import sympy.geometry as gm # a geometry module in sympy
import numpy as np # you might know this

unit=3 # the units of your field

#List of circles from 5 to 30
circles=[gm.Circle(gm.Point(10,10),r) for r in range(5,30)] 

# list of circle perimeters
perimeters=[i.circumference for i in circles]

#number of units for each radius step
num_of_units=[i//unit for i in perimeters]

print(num_of_units)
```